# Free memberships are not created after upgrading to 4.6

Tags: civimember, contribution-page

We just upgraded to 4.6, and are having an issue with our membership sign up contribution page. It is for a free membership, and the page says that it is working, but on the back-end, no membership is being created: just the contact record and Drupal account. Has anyone had a similar issue after upgrading, or have any idea what could be wrong?

I tried to replicate it on the demo site, and could not.

Comment: As an update: this is working for all of our free memberships (we have a few different types). All paid membership sign-ups are working perfectly.

Comment: I think you have a 'not' missing in above as currently it says 'free' and 'paid' are 'working'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The demo site always runs the very latest code, essentially 4.6.3 which will be released tomorrow. Maybe upgrading will solve it?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with civicrm and wordpress but it is now solved by upgrading to 4.6.3